# Is there a way to write a string as serial within tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, communication

I'm trying to send a string from a RaspberryPi 3B+ via USB-cable to a Arduino Uno. Im getting the values in the string from a GUI using Tkinter. When I press a Tkinter button I want the RasPi to send the values.

```py
def dieseFarbe():

    r = Sliderred.get ()
    g = Slidergreen.get ()
    b = Sliderblue.get ()
    w = Sliderwhite.get ()
    f = Sliderfader.get()

    value_string = "{},{},{},{}".format(r, g, b, w)

    #ser.write(value_string)
```

The GUI works perfectly.

```
print(value_string)
```

works without a problem.

```
ser.write(value_string)
```

causes the following errors:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/python-GUI/gui.py", line 22, in dieseFarbe
ser.write(value_string)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 518, in write
d = to_bytes(data)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 63, in to_bytes
raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '1,1,1,1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what you need to do: encode the string to bytes.

You can only send bytes over a serial connection, but python3's `str` is a string of "characters"; i.e., if your GUI sent unicode characters, the serial library wouldn't know how to encode them to bytes.

You can fix this by simply doing:

```py
ser.write(value_string.encode())
```

or `encode("ascii")` or `encode("utf-8")`, whichever is appropriate